# How take define variable value using "if" condition and then insert variable value inside MS Access database

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to insert data into an `MS Access` database, and I'm using a `DataGridView` as `DataSource`. The `DataGridView` is filled with a `select` query that takes data from another database.

I use the `DataGridView` because it is easy for me to loop the `insert` using the `DataGridViewRow`s.
I put some `DataRow`s in variables, then I use two "if"s and one "else" to select one of the fields from the `DataGridView` that contains `DateTime` values and split its data between the two variables that I'll use in the `insert` query.

But I'm not getting any values from the "if", and the variables are inserting "01/01/2001 00:00:00" in only one row of the database, because it soon throws a "duplicate values" error, meaning that the "for" loop is executed, but the conditions inside the "if" are throwing nothing.
Please look at my code an tell me if you can find the problem.
Thanks in advance for your attention.

```
<code>
private void firstLaunchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  dtGV = timeTankDGV.Rows.Count;
  lore = dtGV - 1;
  dtp = dateTimePicker1.Value;
  tiempo.Open(); 
  try
  {
    for (i = 0; i < lore; i++)
    {
      idNum = Convert.ToString(timeTankDGV.Rows[i].Cells["IdentificationNumber"].Value);
      epName = Convert.ToString(timeTankDGV.Rows[i].Cells["Name"].Value);
      idUser = Convert.ToInt32(timeTankDGV.Rows[i].Cells["IdUser"].Value);
      recordType = Convert.ToInt32(timeTankDGV.Rows[i].Cells["RecordType"].Value);
      record = Convert.ToDateTime(timeTankDGV.Rows[i].Cells["RecordTime"].Value);
      // int result1 = record.TimeOfDay- turn1Start.TimeOfDay;
      //int result2 = record.Hour.CompareTo(startLimit1.Hour);
      // int insult1=record.Hour.CompareTo(turn1End.Hour);
      //MessageBox.Show("RecordTime "+record.TimeOfDay);
      //MessageBox.Show("turno1Start "+turn1Start.TimeOfDay);
      //MessageBox.Show("start1Limit "+startLimit1.TimeOfDay);

      if (record.TimeOfDay <= turn1Start.TimeOfDay && record.TimeOfDay >= startLimit1.TimeOfDay && recordType == 0)
      {
        horaEntrada = Convert.ToDateTime(timeTankDGV.Rows[i].Cells["RecordTime"].Value);
        //horaEntrada = Convert.ToDateTime(record.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss tt"));
        //MessageBox.Show("(-_-) " + horaEntrada);
      }
      else
      {
        if (record.TimeOfDay >= turn1End.TimeOfDay && recordType == 1)
        {
          horaSalida = Convert.ToDateTime(timeTankDGV.Rows[i].Cells["RecordTime"].Value);
          //horaSalida = Convert.ToDateTime(record.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss tt"));
          //MessageBox.Show("(-_-) " + horaSalida);
        }
      }
      /**/

      //horaSalida = DateTime.Now;
      OleDbCommand comando = new OleDbCommand();
      comando.Connection = tiempo;
      string consulta = "insert into Horarios (IdUser,IdNumber,Nombre,Turno,RecordType,WorkHourIn,WorkHourOut)" +                         " values(@IdUser,@IdNumber,@Nombre,@Turno,@RecordType,@WorkHourIn,@WorkHourOut)";
      comando.CommandText = consulta;
      OleDbDataAdapter datos = new OleDbDataAdapter(comando);
      turno = 1;
      comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdUser", idUser);
      comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdNumber", idNum.ToString());
      comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", epName.ToString());
      comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Turno", turno);
      comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecordType", recordType);
      //MessageBox.Show("entrada "+horaEntrada);
      comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkHourIn", horaEntrada.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss tt"));
      //MessageBox.Show("salida "+horaSalida);
      comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkHourOut", horaSalida.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss tt"));
      status = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    if (status > 0)
    { 
      MessageBox.Show("insercion completa :-D"); 
    }
    else 
    {
      MessageBox.Show("insercion fallida -_-");
    }
  }     // INSERTED !!!
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("error " + ex);
  }
  finally
  {
    tiempo.Close();
  }
}       // INSERTED !!!
<code>
```

Comment: If you used a DataTable as the datasource (and maybe a DataAdapter), you could get rid of most of that code.  Add/Change/Delete DataRows and just `myDA.Update(myDT)`

Comment: I completed your code formatting and marked the two inserted `}` with `// INSERTED` tags.

Comment: tankyou zx485 for your code_formating help.

Comment: Plutonix. I used that long code because i had some troubles editing and giving parameters to the querys, when using dataAdapters and dataTables (if i understand correctly, and we're talking about the visual studio's dataobject editor). when you end the typing of this code, then, its very easy to make changes to any part of it

Comment: Using *a* DataAdapter and *a* DataTable there is no need to poke data into the DGV: the VIEW part of DGV does that for you.  No need to manage, build or compose single table queries (or parameters): the DataAdapter can be taught how to do that and remember how.  No need to fish data out of the DGV to update the DB; the datatable knows which rows have been changed, added and deleted.  The DA works with it to do just what is needed.  The only bit of that code you *might* need is the conditional part, but both seem to set `horaSalida` to the same value.

Comment: well... i don't really know how to use that dataadapter or datatable, when i used the dataobject editor from the visual studio, i couldn't recreate the ms acces database without destroying the dataobjects, and the ms acces engine does not support the advanced querys, not even the create query. so, i couldn't modify the database structure from inside the visual studio. then, one day, i found this site, and here i learned how to use the oleDb onnection to programatically create database connections, querys and data handling, and i was able to modify the database without loosing the code